# Resolving File paths - 'File not found' error in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, filepath, workspace

My current directory has files registers.xml and MySaxparser.java. But I still get a File not found error when i use new File("register.xml");

My cwd is : C:\Users\nb\workspaceAndroid\MySaxParser

Im using Java 1.7 , Eclipse platform on windows

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
        File file1 = new File("register.xml");
          if(file1.exists()){
              System.out.println("File existed");
          }else{
              System.out.println("File not found!");
          }
   System.out.println("Working Directory = " +  System.getProperty("user.dir"));
```

Output:

```
File not found!
Working Directory = C:\Users\nb\workspaceAndroid\MySaxParser
```

I tried the line below whcih didnt work too.

```
File file1 = new File("C:\\Users\\nb\\workspaceAndroid\\MySaxParser\\register.xml");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use getClass().getResource() to read a file in the classpath:

```
URL url = getClass().getResource("register.xml");
```

Complete code:

```
URL url = getClass().getResource("register.xml");
File file = new File(url.toURI());
```

Comment: this anwser didn't work for me because you cannot call getClass from static class. In case you are working on a static class, e.g. public static main, use the [Name_of_your_Class].class.getResource(...) instead:
  e.g. MySaxParser.class.getResource("register.xml")
for further details see answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17397548/1806436

Answer (score 3):

The current working directory in Eclipse Java project is different from the directory where the files are kept

directory C:\Users\nb\workspaceAndroid\MySaxParser\src

Working dir : C:\Users\nb\workspaceAndroid\MySaxParser

Make sure the file paths are relative to the working directory.