# Universal main method with this.getClass().newInstance()

Tags: java, static, this

Okay, so don't ask why, but I'm trying to make a universal `public static void main()` method. I've already tried to use these two methods;

```
public class Foo {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        try {
            this.getClass().newInstance().check();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void check() {
        System.out.println("Check succesful");
    }
}
```

The error I get is that `this` "Cannot be used in a static context"
Okay, so I know I can't use `this` in a static context, but what I want to know is how I can replace it, without using `Foo.check()`

If possible, how should I do this? If not, I'd like to know why.

Comment: Since main is static it means   there is no this access.  You could do Foo.class.newInstance().check(), but I'm not sure what you are trying to do really

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.8.3

Comment: And if you need more details why you cannot access this from static then please google or read other post on stackoverflow

Comment: Any time you see `this` in a static method, it is not going to work.

Comment: Okay, so I know I can't use `this` in a static method, but how should I replace it, without using `Foo`

Comment: @Charlie you cannot.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8275499/how-to-call-getclass-from-a-static-method-in-java

Comment: You can not do Foo.check() unless check() is static

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at [How to call getClass() from a static method in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8275499/how-to-call-getclass-from-a-static-method-in-java/17397548#17397548) and [Getting the class name from a static method in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/936684/getting-the-class-name-from-a-static-method-in-java/17397143#17397143) something like

```
interface Checkable {
    public void check();
}

public class Foo implements Checkable {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        try {
            Class currentClass = new Object() { }.getClass().getEnclosingClass();
            Checkable instance = (Checkable) currentClass.newInstance();
            instance.check();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void check() {
        System.out.println("Check succesful");
    }
}
```

might do the trick, but I'm not sure I should recommend doing that...

Comment: @Charlie Note that extending this class won't add the main method to the subclass...

Answer (score 2):

`this` is the current instance. You don't have an instance in a static method. Please see [I want to know the difference between static method and non-static method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3903537/i-want-to-know-the-difference-between-static-method-and-non-static-method)

Do this instead:

```
public class Foo {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Foo().check();
  }

  public void check() {
    System.out.println("Check succesful");
  }
}
```

As an answer to the comment (I don't seem to be able to make comments yet): No. The only other way is to make `check()` static as well and call `Foo.check()`, but you didn't want to do that.

Comment: Is it impossible without using `new Foo()` ?

Answer (score 1):

There's no `this` in a static context; that's exactly what static *means*. The approach you're trying will not work. You could perhaps supply the name of the class you're interested in on the command line.

Answer (score 0):

As, I know in java instance variable cannot be accessed in static block util you don't have object of that class for which class you want to access instance variable and this in java is a instance variable. so you cannot access this variable in any static block or you required object reference for this.[for further clarification check here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html).

Answer (score 0):

why dont you try this ?

```
  public class Foo
 {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        try 
        {
            Foo obj = new Foo();
            //  this.getClass().newInstance().check();
             obj.check();
        }
        catch(Exception e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void check() 
    {
        System.out.println("Check succesful");
    }
}
```